# I can't to generate a PDF file with Python and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, windows, jinja2, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I hope that y'all fine, I'm developing an app in Python that one of its functions is to generate a PDF file, but when I try to do it, it raise this exception:

```
  File "D:\Projects\CORE\venv\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 158, in handle_error
raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, error_msg))
OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

I'll share you my code:

```
path_template = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'administration\extras')
            template_loader =jinja2.FileSystemLoader(path_template)
            env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
            template = env.get_template('template.html')

            html = template.render({
                'fecha_sesion': fecha_sesion
            })

        options = {
            'page-size': 'Letter',
            'margin-top': '0.05in',
            'margin-right': '0.05in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.05in',
            'margin-left': '0.05in',
            'encoding': 'UTF-8'
        }

        config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe') # <---- El ERROR ahora está acá
        ruta_salida = 'D:\Projects\CORE\administration\extras\pdftest.pdf'

        pdfkit.from_string(html, ruta_salida, options=options, configuration=config)
```

I've been using the libraries jinja2 and pdfkit apart to wkhtmltopdf and this one seem to be the problem, I added to the Path in the environment variables the route of wkhtmltopdf.